# Is the ability to change disabled combo-box BackColor a bug or a feature?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have found the following solution:
If I put in the designer:

```
this.comboBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;  //or any other color
this.comboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList; //it has to be that style
```

I'm able to change the color of `comboBox1` - it won't always be grey.

It should be DropDownList and also BackColor should be placed in the designer.

Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: Well there are a number of people asking around these forums to do just what you found out.  So I'm sure they'd call it a feature.

Answer (score 5):

Make custom combobox, and then in `WndProc` set `BackColor` for disabled control.

```
public class ComboBoxCustom : ComboBox {
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr CreateSolidBrush(int color);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    internal static extern int SetBkColor(IntPtr hdc, int color);

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        IntPtr brush;
        switch (m.Msg){

            case (int)312:
                SetBkColor(m.WParam, ColorTranslator.ToWin32(this.BackColor));
                brush = CreateSolidBrush(ColorTranslator.ToWin32(this.BackColor));
                m.Result = brush;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How long have I been searching for this. Works like a charm, thanks Milos!

Answer (score 2):

The DropDownList is allowed the change of BackColor, and no need to set the colour in the Designer, just set the comboBox property to DropDownList in the properties pane.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this problem, but thanks to `DropDownStyle` property which received `ComboBoxStyle` enum to set style.

```
yourCombo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

Answer (score 1):

A disabled control has a *default* `BackColor = Color.Grey`. It is intended to be changed.

**Edit:**

I believe it is just *'that simple'*. Yes, when you start customizing the colors, code must be provided to set the control's properties in all states. Think of it this way: .Net makes the assumption that if you are going to customize a property, you are taking responsibility for always setting the property.

Derived from the [`Control` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36cd312w.aspx), `comboBox1` exposes the [`Control.EnabledChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabledchanged.aspx) event. This is where your logic needs to be implemented to set your own default values for an enabled and disabled state; for instance:

```
private void radioButton1_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((ComboBox)sender).Enabled)
    {
        // set BackColor for enabled state
    }
    else
    {
        // set BackColor for disabled state
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is not that simple at all:

Comment: 1) The BackColor doesn't change when the enabled state is changed. 2) BackColor has weird issue: when I change its default color in properties window and after that change it back - the default color stays in the designer -you can see that it gets bold. It isn't happen with other properties - when it gets back to default value - the value gets regular font, i.e is being removed from the designer.

Comment: You right, I can set another backcolor, but only if the combo box is dropdownlist and its default backcolor was set either in the designer or in the form load event, you will be able actually to see another backcolor, when the combo box is disabled. It is even enough to set: ComboBox1.BackColor= ComboBox1.BackColor; because the control somehow responds to the set, even when there was no change.  Please, check it. (I'm not a junior in C#...